# Question about the word "distance" in this context of driving

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning, legalese

> A driver who wants to pass a bicyclist must do so at a **distance** no less than three feet, unless unable to do so due to traffic or roadway conditions. In these cases, the driver must slow to a reasonable and safe speed, and pass only when doing so does not create a hazard.

3 feet distance from side or from behind of the bicycle?

Comment: When you pass a vehicle having *certain distance*, it's the distance you maintain with it from the side.

Comment: Agree - 3 feet at the side. Coming within 3 feet behind a cyclist is Very Bad Driving, whether the driver is passing or (especially) not passing the cyclist.

Comment: Logically speaking, you *can't* pass a bicycle when you're 3 feet behind them; you'd run over them instead of passing them.  Similarly, you can't pass them when you're 3 feet in front of them, because you're already past them.  Therefore, 3 feet to the side is the only reasonable way to interpret the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the California Driver Handbook. It just says three feet. But the photo clearly shows side by side.
[image]

If were the bicyclist, honestly I would not care from which direction three feet distance is.

So as a language question I would say distance can be any direction unless specified. Legally, you should check your local regulations.

Comment: Really, you'd be perfectly fine on your bicycle with a car driving 3 feet behind you??

Comment: It is wrong to hit bicycles with your car. I'm glad they cleared that up with that helpful picture.

Answer (score 0):

Quite accidentally, I found this:[image: this]

(A quick search online shows it's in Phoenix, Arizona.)